# Nuxt-auth doesn't see any cookies

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Nuxt-auth doesn't see any cookies. Doesn't 'connect.sid' cookie. 
**nuxt.config.js auth settings:**

```
auth: {
strategies: {
  cookie: {
    cookie: {
      prefix: '',
      name: 'test',
    },
    options: {
      expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20000000000).getTime(),
      maxAge: 31622400,
    },
    user: {
      property: 'data',
      autoFetch: false,
    },
    endpoints: {
      login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', withCredentials: true },
      logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'delete' },
    },
  },
},
```

},

**However browser has the cookies (not 'httpOnly'):**
'auth._token.cookie': true
'connect.sid': '213lkj123123fsdsf'
'auth.strategy': 'cookie'
'auth._token_expiration.cookie': false
'i18n_redirected': 'en'

Comment: could you solve this?